# Keycloak- get all users by client

Tags: php, symfony, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I was investigating the Keycloak [documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/4.8/rest-api/index.html#_map).

I am not able to find one endpoint that I need.
In my Symfony project so far I have made to:

1. get an access token
2. extract the access token
3. Use it to get userId if needed

What I could not find is an endpoint from which I could **list users who have authorized a given clientId** .
Does that endpoint exists?

If not, what is the best approach to accomplish this?

***NOTE**: We are still using Keycloak version 5.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I could not find is an endpoint from which I could get all users
> by cliendId . Does that endpoint exists?

No, such endpoint does not exist because (in Keycloak) users are defined at the Realm Level, hence tight to a given realm, not to a given client. The clients are the conceptual representation of things such as applications that users of a certain realm can use to (for instance) request tokens.